# Rubocop and Capybara: detecting forgotten focus: :true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rubocop

As a Rails developper, I got used to work with Rubocop on my CI, and one of the basic feature I like is the detection of forgotten debugger entries, like `byebug`.

There is another string that can easily be forgotten: `:focus` or `focus: :true` in Capybara feature specs. It just happened in my team, and we are looking for a way to prevent it.

I have seen [rubocop-rspec](https://github.com/backus/rubocop-rspec), but apparently that case is not covered.

What is the most efficient option?

Comment: RuboCop RSpec should cover it: https://github.com/backus/rubocop-rspec/blob/master/lib/rubocop/cop/rspec/focus.rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rubocop](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop-rspec/1.7.0/RuboCop/Cop/RSpec/Focus) already checks for `focus: true` and `:focus`. Make sure your team didn't disable the cop.

```
# bad
describe MyClass, focus: true do
end

# bad
describe MyClass, :focus do
end

# good
fdescribe MyClass do
end

# good
describe MyClass do
end
```

Comment: cool, that needs to install rubocop-rspec apparently. We don't have that specific library yet, but we will try soon !

Comment: I don't think so because, `rubocop-rspec` doesn't appear in Rubocop's runtime dependencies: https://rubygems.org/gems/rubocop

Comment: It doesn't seem to be currently being developed but check out this one. It may be still working: https://github.com/lovewithfood/rubocop-rspec-focused

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea to configure RSpec to ignore :focus when on CI too - so all your tests get run even if a lingering :focus is left behind.  For instance that can be done on Travis with

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.filter_run_including focus: true unless ENV['TRAVIS']
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true
end
```